# installing and running Redis and Memcached on Xampp on Windows

Tags: apache, redis, xampp, windows-10, memcached

I have a Win 10 (Creator edition) PC, running Xampp with Apache and MySQL.

I need to install and run Redis and Memcache**d** (not memcache) on it.

I've looked it up and found out that all I need to do is to enable the existing extensions located in the */xampp/php/ext* folder for these components.

So:

1. I don't have a DLL file for memcached (again, not memcache) there.
   (everything I found for this matter is talking about enabling the existing extension, but again - I need memcached and not memcache)
2. I do have the php_redis.dll file under the */xampp/php/ext* folder and I enable it in the php.ini file, but when I run "phpinfo()" in my code, I don't see "redis" in the list of running components there.

What am I missing here and how can I get these two "clowns" to run on my Win-based Xampp system??